# Django: Multiple forms based on related OneToOne objects

Tags: django, forms, view, one-to-one

I have two models:

```
class Question (models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hobby = models.ForeignKey(Hobby)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer (models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    attach_file = models.FileField(upload_to='Attachments', blank=True)
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer
```

I am trying to build a page (similar to Django Admin site views) listing Question objects with Answer form. So as in:

Question 1 -- Answer 1: [text box], [optional attachment]

Question 2 -- Answer 2: [text box], [optional attachment]

*
*
*

Question n -- Answer n: [text box], [optional attachment]

I was first thinking if I could get it working with formset and query like:

```
query=Answer.objects.filter("all answer objects that are related to all question objects related to "hobby1")
```

but haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Currently, I have a view that displays all the questions with "<a href...". I can view and edit each answer separately on their respective views (e.g. contoso.com/hobby1/answer/1/edit).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to have separate models connected via a OneToOneField? You could simplify this by combining the two models.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like it would fit perfectly with the formset. I think I then need to have answer fields optional in the model to allow admin create the questions. I would then need to change the question field not editable by users and change answer fields required=True in the form itself. I guess these things were something why I thought it would be simpler to separate the two. Will try out the combined model.